# Win2K8 R2, out-of-order SID

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-identity, security-identifier

how comes that the SID on a domain are out-of-order ? by out-of-order I mean that the Relative-ID (the very last part of the SID) of some recently created accounts is lower than the one of much older accounts. I always though the Relative-ID was allocated in a pure monotonic ascendant way.

I googled but found no clue. any idea ?

Windows 2008-R2, 5 DC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this has to do with the way relative identifiers are allocated when there is more than one DC i na domain: each DC has its own pool of relative identifiers, hence the apparent non-continuity of allocated SIDs.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc961984.aspx